# Vulkan SDK Version Compatibility for Extensions

Tags: vulkan

The version compatibility of Vulkan SDK is documented in [LunarG's whitepaper](https://www.lunarg.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Vulkan-SDK-Version-Compatibility_4_20.pdf), but I'd like to know whether those extensions controlled by the flags listed below are following the same rule as well.

```
VK_USE_PLATFORM_DIRECTFB_EXT
VK_USE_PLATFORM_ANDROID_KHR
VK_USE_PLATFORM_FUCHSIA
VK_USE_PLATFORM_IOS_MVK
VK_USE_PLATFORM_MACOS_MVK
VK_USE_PLATFORM_METAL_EXT
VK_USE_PLATFORM_VI_NN
VK_USE_PLATFORM_WAYLAND_KHR
VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR
VK_USE_PLATFORM_XCB_KHR
VK_USE_PLATFORM_XLIB_KHR
VK_USE_PLATFORM_XLIB_XRANDR_EXT
VK_USE_PLATFORM_GGP
VK_USE_PLATFORM_SCREEN_QNX
VK_ENABLE_BETA_EXTENSIONS
```

I believe if the `VK_ENABLE_BETA_EXTENSIONS` is enabled, then the version compatibility is not guaranteed, but how about those platform extensions?

Comment: You might want to say explicitly what kind of "compatibility rule" you mean to avoid misunderstadings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, SDK copies the versioning of the specification. If the SDK version is same or higher, the headers should include all the functionality published with a given spec version(and protected by an appropriate macro, as you listed them), and layers should not break (exept for an occasional bug).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you also provide some citations?

Comment: @Gnimuc https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.2.170.0/windows/getting_started.html SDK Versioning